# How to get payment confirmation when Bitcoin is processed in java.

Tags: bitcoind, zeromq

I'm using Bitcoind and ZMQ. I want to get a confirmation via socket when a payment is confirmed.

I'm new to these things and don't know how to start.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is quite a broad question, ZMQ is not bitcoin-specific, perhaps you could find a more general Java ZMQ example? Maybe https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq ?

Comment: Any implementation example will also be helpful. I have checked almost every online links related to it. But didn't get any liks that works for me.

Comment: I just provided one?

Comment: Well, I have figured it out that how to use ZMQ with bitcoin TX id.

Thanks @MeshCollider